# iOS: How to write to a file at a specific directory in the project?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, file

I'm trying to output some strings I've gathered in my app to a text file.

The text files will always exist in my project, like so:

I'm trying to overwrite whatever is in the file with a new (multi-lined) string:

```
func writeFile(){

let theFile: FileHandle? = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: "./MyFiles/file.txt")

if theFile != nil { // This is always nil!!!
    let data = ("Some text\nline 2\nline3\n" as String).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    // Write it to the file
    theFile?.write(data!)

    // Close the file
    theFile?.closeFile()
}
else {
    print("Writing failed.")
}

} // End file writing
```

However, the FileHandler always returns nil. I suspect that this is because I'm supplying the path and/or filename incorrectly?

I've been googling and stack overflowing for a couple of hours now... And still no idea of how to fix the problem. How do I specify the correct location and file?

Comment: The application bundle is read-only.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. My goal now is to write to the documents directory, but I'm still unsure of how to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot write file outside of the application sandbox. Each iOS app have individual directories Document, Library, tmp to store data.

```
func writeFile(){

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentationDirectory,.userDomainMask,true)
    let theFile: FileHandle? = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: "\(documentsPath)/MyFiles/file.txt")

    if theFile != nil { // This is always nil!!!
        let data = ("Some text\nline 2\nline3\n" as String).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        // Write it to the file
        theFile?.write(data!)

        // Close the file
        theFile?.closeFile()
    }
    else {
        print("Writing failed.")
    }

} // End file writing
```

Comment: I get an error " Extraneous argument labels 'NSSearchPathDirectory:NSSearchPathDomainMask:' " for the line

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory:0,NSSearchPathDomainMask:0,true)

I'm not sure what's going on, it seems there is an extra argument?

Writing to the documents directory will be fine for my purposes, should I use 1 argument over the other?

Comment: It looks like the syntax has changed since you wrote your answer.  This article has a version which should be compatible with the latest version of Swift: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/writing-data-to-the-documents-directory

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to overwrite whatever is in the file

You can't. Writing into the app bundle is forbidden.

The proper approach in this kind of situation is, on first launch, to copy the files into, say, the Documents folder, which is writable. Now you can access them from there, and they are both readable and writable.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'm new to Swift, so unfortunately that leaves me with a very similar question: How do I write to a file in the documents directory?

Comment: Okay, but that's been answered a zillion times before. Look at the FileManager class.