# How to write to a file in a project while the project is running?

Tags: swift, xcode, bundle

I have a file in a project that I would like to write to, I named it "Container" and gave it the file ending "json".  So it is fully named: "Container.json".  It is an empty json file.  When I try the following code, none of the errors are thrown, however, when I look at the file, it is empty.  How can I write to my local json file in my project? Is that not a permitted capability?

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        try! Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Container", withExtension: "json")!
            .write(content: "test")
        print("reached")
    }
}

extension URL {
    func write(content: String) throws {
        try content.write(
            to: self,
            atomically: true,
            encoding: .utf8
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You can’t modify anything inside the app bundle so you need to keep this file elsewhere.

Comment: You can't. Files in the application bundle are read-only (for obvious reasons).

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584086/ios-how-to-write-to-a-file-at-a-specific-directory-in-the-project and this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/writing-data-to-the-documents-directory - I had the exact same question as you do and these answered it for me

Comment: Actually, this question might be a duplicate of the first link

Comment: @vadian, are the obvious reasons for security? Or because the app itself is a binary at runtime? And so the files might not exist if only the binary is shared? Seems like it could just return nil then.  Is there some reason the program needs to be deterministic?

Comment: Yes, for security. The entire app bundle is code signed  and a hash value is created. If one byte is modified the app won’t launch.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you.